# Import only once a plugin in hapijs and use it everywhere

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

I should use a plugin named `hapi-mongoose-db-connector` into my hapijs application. In the repository page the developers suggest the ways you can import correctly it. It says that the following way is the bad way:

```
# from the server
mongoose = server.pack.plugins['hapi-mongoose-db-connector'].mongoose
# or from a plugin
mongoose = plugin.plugins['hapi-mongoose-db-connector'].mongoose
```

and discourages using it. Instead he recommends to do in the following way:

> You do nothing and just require mongoose in your plugins. As npm
>   requires are singletons (the code is loaded only once this works very
>   well)

but he doesn't show any examples. At this point I'm not pretty sure how to use it. I wouldn't call in every js files `mongoose`. I would call it once in my application somewhere and in my js files where I create models for the database, use it. Do you know any best practices in those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, first one is the hapi way doing this kind of thing.

But as the mongoose module is a **singleton**, that plugin just require mongoose and initialize it [[1]](https://github.com/codedoctor/hapi-mongoose-db-connector/blob/master/src/index.coffee) after load that plugin into hapi, you can use mongoose in any file;

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
```